# Can a telegram bot running on node.js be hacked

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Lets say we have a telegram bot running on node.js using node library: **node-telegram-bot-api**

Do we need to worry about any security problems, like can someone hack my server and access the source code or data through the API connection?

Comment: The bot can be served in two modes, one is long polling other is webhooks. long polling is more secure and your firewall will likely protect from external requests. If you use the other approach, you should be more cautious. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it, every API connection is through [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS), which is regarded as safe.

Comment: but I thought it uses polling to get the messages?